# Порт 6000 недоступен

Tags: python, http, fastapi, uvicorn

Обнаружил неработающий порт в FastAPI. Запускаю на 6000 порте и оказывается, сервер недоступен. Соседние порты работают.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
import uvicorn


HOST = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = int(6000)


app = FastAPI()


@app.get('/')
async def get_courses_method():
    return {}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host=HOST, port=PORT)
```

Comment: Какая ОС? Что выдаёт `netstat`? (Если *nix, то скорее всего конфликт с X11). В общем, `man netstat` (или чего-то там типа `netstat /h`, если Windows). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это не ошибка `FastAPI`. *Safari, Firefox, Chrome* и, возможно, другие браузеры будут запрещать запросы на порт **6000**, поскольку он обычно используется для протокола **X11**, а не для просмотра веб-страниц.

[Здесь](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/refs/heads/master/net/base/port_util.cc) вы можете увидеть список запрещенных портов в исходном коде *Chrome*, среди которых порт **6000**

Дополнительное чтение [здесь](https://medium.com/@msinha2801/why-are-some-ports-considered-unsafe-restricted-c3c22d0596c0) и [тут](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1025)